# HintTextColor Issue in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Even after using android:textColorHint tag the color of the hint text is not changing.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
        android:id="@+id/order_desc"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:hint="Order description"
        android:textColorHint="#982360"
        app:met_baseColor="#D8000000"
        app:met_errorColor="@color/fab_material_red_500"
        app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
        app:met_floatingLabelText="Description"
        app:met_hideUnderline="true"
        app:met_primaryColor="#982360">

        <requestFocus />
    </com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText>
```

Comment: There is no need to use library in the first place. Use AppCompact and you should have your edittext according to material specs

Answer (score 0):

You should define the color in an xml file specifically for colors, and reference the colors like so: `android:textColorHint="@color/black"`

Comment: So you mean android:textColorHint="#982360" this is not working?